# Database sessions

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

When I am executing the query:

```
select count(*),type from v$session group by type;
```

then I get the following output:

```
count(*)  type
----------------
1         User
22        Background
```

What does this Background imply in v$session?
Thank You

Comment: Sessions of background processes means? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Read the document he linked, it explains everything you need to know

Answer (score 4):

That means you have 22 sessions of background processes(Like SMON, PMON, LGWR etc) Please visit the following Oracle Documentation link for details.

> To maximize performance and accommodate many users, a multiprocess
>   Oracle system uses some additional Oracle processes called background
>   processes

[Process Architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/process.htm)